# Please verify my delta-epsilon limit proof of $\lim_{x\to1} x^2 -6x = -5$

Tags: analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I want to prove that the limit exists using the delta-epsilon limit definition. Please somebody verify my solution.
The given problem is $$\lim_{x\to1} x^2 -6x = -5.$$
My solution:

Let $ε>0$. Choose $δ>0$ such that $0<δ<1$ and $0<δ<ε/3$.

If $0<|x-1|< δ$, then $|x^2-6x+5| = |(x-5)(x-1)| = |x-5| |x-1|< |x-5|δ < 3δ < ε$

Scratch work:
Assume that $δ≤1$, then $|x-1|<δ<1$ implies that $-1<x-1<1$ and $0<x<2$ so that $$5<|x-5|<3.$$

Comment: I think you need to ask that on a maths site.

Comment: Also, there's a typo in the second line of the argument: `0<|x-1|<` what?

Comment: [math.se], specifically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mathematics question and is best suited for Math SE !

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Please post your next math question to the math.stackexchange page.

Since it is short: The principle of your calculation is sound, up to the factorization. However

```
|x-5| = |x-1-4| ≤ |x-1|+4 < 5
```

so that initially you need `δ<ε/5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your scratch work is good up to this point:

$$5<|x-5|<3.$$

This is a claim that $5 < 3$, which is clearly wrong. In fact, from
$0 < x < 2$ you can find that $-5 < x-5 < -3$,
but in taking the absolute value you change the sign of all the numbers in
these inequalities and therefore you reverse the direction of the
inequalities: $a < b$ implies $-b < -a$,
and  $-5 < x-5 < -3$ implies $3 < -(x-5) < 5$.
Since this shows that $-(x-5)$
is necessarily positive, you can then
substitute $\lvert x - 5 \rvert$ for $-(x-5)$ in the inequalities:

$$3<|x-5|<5.$$

You therefore have a bound of $5\delta$ where you wrote $3\delta$,
and therefore  you want $\delta < \varepsilon/5$ rather than 
$\delta < \varepsilon/3$. (The other conditions, $0 < \delta$
and $\delta < 1$, are OK and are necessary for your argument.)